# AutoHotkey XButton1 Simulating Control

Tags: autohotkey

I've been at this for an hour now with no luck. I've tried different ways and have yet to figure this out.
Basically I'm playing a game, and in that game, in order for you to jump, you have to have Control held down. So I want to make it so that while I'm holding my Mouse Button 4 down (XButton1), it also simulates Control being held down. Then when I let up off XButton1, control also lets off. Also I need to suspend the original task for XButton1 while doing this.
If anyone can help, I'd greatly appreciate it. I've tried atleast 6 or 7 different ways. Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

**AHK Script 1**

XButton1 Down::

Send, {Ctrl Down}

**AHK Script 2**

XButton1 Up::

Send, {Ctrl Up}

Comment: You don't need to put these in two different scripts.  Put a `return` statement after each.  `XButton1::` is also equivalent to `XButton1 Down::`